# Visual studio error: implicit declaration of function

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

why is this error coming implicit declaration of function 'scanf_s'. scanf is not working in visual studio even after writing scanf_s instead of scanf?.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    int a;
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("\n%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Typo anyway - `scanf_s("%d, &a");` should be `scanf_s("%d", &a);`. Aside: the newline usage is haphazard - add `\n` *after* "hello" and move the other one too, like `"%d\n"`.

Comment: Are you building this for a normal Microsoft Windows console environment?

Comment: The implication is that `scanf()` is unknown too.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry i wrote the wrong code but it still showing the same problem

Comment: Presumably you need to set the "include" paths somewhere so that the compiler can find the header files (and the linker can find the library files). Does the program compile when you use `scanf()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane when using scanf() its just showing [Running] cd "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C lang\" && gcc first.c -o first && "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C lang\"first
but it is not stopping or exiting, just showing running. i have seen people getting not secure error ,but i didn't get it. only showing the RUNNING part

Comment: In that case the compiler found the standard function `scanf()` but does not support `scanf_s()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane what to do now?

Comment: The reason your code is still running is because it is waiting for you to input a value.

Comment: @WeatherVane without a prompt?. i wrote the prompt for the question

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the prompt. Are you still usign the version without a newline output?

Comment: @WeatherVane i am very new to programing. needed a compiler to study c but its been nightmare

Comment: @using fflush(stdout); just prints the prompt is there any solution;

Comment: @IanAbbott i need this code to submit assignment

Comment: That was what you asked for. Now enter the numeric value for the `scanf` to accept. Please see [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @WeatherVane you don't understand, i cant enter value

Comment: Add another `fflush(stdout);` and `getchar();` before `return;` so that the console remains open so you can read the output. Aside: don't do this `printf("\n%d",a);` it's almost never what you need. Instead do this `printf("%d\n",a);`

Comment: Just use `scanf()`.  `scanf_s()` is an **optional** function that's Microsoft-only for real-world purposes, and it's no safer than the standard `scanf()` ([Microsoft **originated** the term "FUD"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt), after all...), `scanf()` hasn't been "deprecated" by anyone but Microsoft.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm